# Could somebody help me with some Dynamic SQL knowledge

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am attempting to create my own procedure for searching for text strings across the database but I keep getting a dynamic SQL related error. I am aware that there are other procedures out there that are available but I just wanted to attempt to create my own just to practice. It's been a while and I still can't figure this out...

```
    USE AdventureWorks2014
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @colname nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @searchstring nvarchar(max) = 'Ken'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Results
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dynamic') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Dynamic 

CREATE TABLE #Results (tablename nvarchar(max), colname nvarchar(128))
CREATE TABLE #Dynamic (colname nvarchar(128))

WHILE @tablename IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @colname = ''
SET @tablename = (
                    SELECT MIN(SCHEMA_NAME(ta.schema_id) + '.' + ta.name)
                        FROM sys.tables ta
                            WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(ta.schema_id) + '.' + ta.name > @tablename
                                AND ta.object_id IN (
                                                        SELECT DISTINCT(c.object_id)
                                                        FROM sys.columns c
                                                            JOIN sys.types t
                                                                ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                                                                AND t.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar','char','name')

                                                    )
                    )
WHILE (@tablename IS NOT NULL) AND (@colname IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @colname = (
                    SELECT MIN(c.name)
                    FROM sys.columns c
                    JOIN sys.types t
                    ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                    AND t.name IN ('nvarchar', 'varchar','char','name')
                    AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
                    and c.name > @colname
                )

IF @colname IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @tablename = QUOTENAME(@tablename)
SET @colname = QUOTENAME(@colname)
INSERT INTO #Results 
EXEC
    (
        'SELECT '+ @colname + 
        ' FROM ' +@TableName +
        ' WHERE ' + @colname + ' IN ' + @SearchString

    )
END
END
END
```

Comment: [Why is  "Can someone help me?" not a real question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576) And writing *I keep getting errors* is an absolutely useless problem description. The *errors* you're getting are right on your screen in front of you. There is absolutely no reason for you to fail to include them in your post so we have the information available as well. You're asking us to donate our time to solve **your** problem; you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so by including the relevant details that are **right on your screen**.

Answer (score 0):

Here - I think this works. I made several changes, but note I built the queries as strings and used sp_executesql to run them. A benefit of that is that you can print the output and execute it in another window to make sure it works.

There are a few print statements - I used them to check each piece as I progressed through your script. I left them in so you can kind of see the thought process of checking one piece at a time.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tableplusschema nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @colname nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @searchstring nvarchar(max) = 'Ken'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Results
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dynamic') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Dynamic 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableName') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TableName
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ColName') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ColName

CREATE TABLE #TableName (tableplusschema nvarchar(max))
CREATE TABLE #ColName (colname nvarchar(max))
CREATE TABLE #Results (tablename nvarchar(max), colname nvarchar(128), value nvarchar(max))
CREATE TABLE #Dynamic (colname nvarchar(128))

WHILE @tableplusschema IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @colname = ''
    DELETE FROM #TableName;
    SET @qry = '    
                INSERT INTO #TableName (tableplusschema) SELECT MIN(SCHEMA_NAME(ta.schema_id) + ''.'' + ta.name)
                FROM sys.tables ta
                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(ta.schema_id) + ''.'' + ta.name > ''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableplusschema, '[', ''), ']', '') + '''
                AND ta.object_id IN (
                                        SELECT DISTINCT(c.object_id)
                                        FROM sys.columns c
                                        JOIN sys.types t
                                        ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                                        AND t.name IN (''varchar'', ''nvarchar'',''char'',''name'')
                                    )
                '
    print @qry
    exec sp_executesql @qry
    SELECT top 1 @tableplusschema = tableplusschema, @tablename = right(tableplusschema, len(tableplusschema) - charindex('.', tableplusschema)) from #TableName
    print @tableplusschema
    print @tablename

    WHILE (@tableplusschema IS NOT NULL) AND (@colname IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM #ColName;
        SET @qry = 'INSERT INTO #ColName (colname) SELECT MIN(c.name)
                    FROM sys.columns c
                    JOIN sys.types t
                    ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
                    AND t.name IN (''nvarchar'', ''varchar'',''char'',''name'')
                    AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableplusschema, '[', ''), ']', '') + ''')
                    and c.name > ''' +  REPLACE(REPLACE(@colname, '[', ''), ']', '') + ''''
        print @qry
        exec sp_executesql @qry

        SELECT TOP 1 @colname = REPLACE(REPLACE(colname, '[', ''), ']', '') FROM #ColName

        print @colname
        IF @colname IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            --SET @tableplusschema = QUOTENAME(@tableplusschema)
            SET @colname = QUOTENAME(@colname)

            SET @qry = 'INSERT INTO #Results (tablename, colname, value) SELECT '''+ @tableplusschema + ''', ''' + @colname + 
                    ''', ' + @colname + ' FROM ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableplusschema, '[', ''), ']', '') +
                    ' WHERE ' + @colname + ' LIKE ''%' + @SearchString + '%'''
            print @qry
            exec sp_executesql @qry
        END
    END
END

SELECT * FROM #Results
```

Comment: Thanks Max, this is really helpful. My mistake was in how i was executing the dynamic sql statement. Good thinking with adding some more dynamic sql into the code.